# c# listbox selectedItem not working

Tags: c#, listbox, selecteditem

Ok, I would like somebody to try this and give me a specific working answer. 
I have a ListBox control that has items and I have an event handler for ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateTextBox2(); //sets the selectedIndexItem to textbox2
}
```

In another function I have this code:

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex = (listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) % listBox1.Items.Count;
```

It does move to the next item but it doesn't raise the event.

I have also tried this without raising an event

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex = (listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) % listBox1.Items.Count;
updateTextBox2(); //
```

but the listbox item is still not copied into the textbox until I actual click on the listbox

Comment: what is ur need  ?/ and post code related to `updateTextBox2()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateTextBox1(); 
    }

    private void updateTextBox1()
    {
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = (listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) % listBox1.Items.Count;
        listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
    }
```

if you are wanting to raise the event though another method, you need to use

```
listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
```

the event is only raised automaticaly when you invoke it.
Also you could just invoke the update method, id need to see more code to understand why it wouldn't work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = (listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) % listBox1.Items.Count;
        updateTextBox1();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it works for ListBox, but I know it does for ListView so it's worth a shot. Try setting the selection like this instead:

```
listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Selected = false; // Not 100% sure the Items have a Selected property
listBox1.Items[(listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) % listBox1.Items.Count].Selected = true;
```

That might fire the event.